# Prometheus queries to get CPU and Memory usage in kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, promql

I need to get CPU and Memory usage in kubernetes pods with prometheus queries. Can someone plz help?

Comment: Please provide more information on your current situation. Is Prometheus up and running but you don't know how to query for metrics? Are you having trouble getting Prometheus running in your cluster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count k8s cluster cpu/memory usage with prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866777/count-k8s-cluster-cpu-memory-usage-with-prometheus)

Comment: yes. it's up and running I want get alerts for CPU and Memory usage of the pods. 
For that I need to have prometheus queries. Plz can I have what u r using ?

Comment: I want to have something like this 
"sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="$namespace", pod_name="$pod", container_name!="POD"}) by (container_name)" Since there are variables in this query Im unable to send alerts.

Comment: Please edit your question with whatever query you tried.

Answer (score 15):

For CPU percentage

```
avg((sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total {container_name!="" ,pod="<Pod name>" } [5m])) by (namespace , pod, container ) / on (container , pod , namespace) ((kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores >0)*300))*100)
```

For Memory percentage

```
avg((avg (container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod="<pod name>"}) by (container_name , pod ))/ on (container_name , pod)(avg (container_spec_memory_limit_bytes>0 ) by (container_name, pod))*100)
```

you can use above promql with pod name in a query.

Comment: why are you multiplying with 300

Answer (score 5):

The following query should return per-pod number of used CPU cores:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) without (container)
```

The following query should return per-pod [RSS memory usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size):

```
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container!=""}) without (container)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) about `container!=""` filter in queries above.

If you need summary CPU and memory usage across all the pods in Kubernetes cluster, then just remove `without (container)` suffix from queries above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use prometheus-operator to collect data from kubernetes?
If yes, you can use something like this:
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes)
sum(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total)
Just for example.

Comment: I want to have something like this 
"sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="$namespace", pod_name="$pod", container_name!="POD"}) by (container_name)" Since there are variables in this query Im unable to send alerts.

Answer (score -1):

To better monitor the memory usage of Pod/Containers. The `container_memory_max_usage_bytes` should also be used to monitor besides `container_memory_working_set_bytes`.

---

We used to monitor the memory usage of the pod through

```
avg(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container!="POD"}) by (pod)  / (avg(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{container!="POD"} > 0) by (pod)) *100
```

However, we met the OOMKilled of the pod and failed to find anything abnormal from the above metrics.

---

Through the `container_memory_max_usage_bytes` we find the abnormal memory usage of the pod.

```
avg(container_memory_max_usage_bytes{ container!="POD"}) by (pod)  / (avg(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{ container!="POD"} > 0) by (pod)) *100
```