# How to get CPU, memory metrics for Kubernetes Jobs, CronJobs, BatchJobs and KedaJobs

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, jobs, cadvisor

Is there a way to get CPU, memory metrics in Prometheus for Kubernetes Jobs, CronJobs, Batch Jobs and KedaJobs.

Currently I can get all this metrics from Prometheus about the time, status, etc. I have been trying to get the CPU metrics using cadvisor but I don't see any CPU and memory metrics for my jobs.

I have been trying by exposing a port and a service for cadvisor to get the metrics but still doesn't work.

There are going to be multiple jobs and I need the CPU and memory metrics from each so I cannot add the manually to the Prometheus config, is there a way to do this.

Any recommendation I can try, Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you check this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/cronjob-metrics.md) for cron job metrics and refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63806947/19230181) by Peter to get CPU and Memory usage in kubernetes pods.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: @HemanthKumar sorry for taking so long in answering back, I was not getting those metrics and after deploying cadvisor and the newest version of kube-state-metrics. I was getting those metrics, I still needed to add a port and a service to my jobs to be able to get the metrics out of the pods. But my problem now is that those metrics:
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total and container_cpu_usage_seconds_total are not being kept and dissapear after some time, the other metric I am using kube_pod_container_resource_requests is being kept, still don't know why